# Stretching internal content inside the cell iText 7 PDF

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I still fight with iText, and it looks like he's running over me. 
I already asked the question here, but most likely the question was so abstract that I could not get answers.

So, I have a table with two cells - notesCell and priceCell:

```
public void GenerateTable(SimpleProductVM product)
{
    // Create the table
    var productTable = new Table(new float[] { 1, 1 })
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
        .SetKeepTogether(true);

    // Create a cell of the notes
    var notesCell = CreateNotesCell(product.AdditionalAttributes);

    // Create a cell of the price
    var priceCell = CreatePriceCell(product.Price);

    // Add all of the cells
    productTable.AddRange(notesCell, priceCell);

    var writer = new PdfWriter(PathToFile);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    var document = new Document(pdfDocument);

    document.Add(productTable);

    document.Close();
}
```

In each cell(notesCell, priceCell), I have an inner table. I want this internal table to be stretched across the size of the parent cell. 
This is my code for creating two cells(notesCell, priceCell):

```
private Cell CreateNotesCell(IList<ProductAttribute> notes)
{
    // Create a notes cell
    var notesCell = new Cell()
        .SetPadding(10);

    // Create an inner table for the notes
    var tableNotes = new Table(1)
        .SetBackgroundColor(RegularBackgroundColor)
        .SetMargin(10)
        // if I set the width in percent, 
        //then the table is stretched to the width of the parent cell
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
        // But if I set the height in percent,
        // the table is not stretched to the height of the parent cell!!!!
        .SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

    // Add a header of the inner table
    tableNotes.AddHeaderCell(new TextCell("Примечание",
        BoldFont, TitleForegroundColor, false));

    // Fill the inner table
    foreach(var note in notes)
        tableNotes.AddCell(new TextCell($"{note.Name}: {string.Join(", ", note.Options)}", 
            LightFont, RegularForegroundColor));

    // Add the inner table to the parent cell
    notesCell.Add(tableNotes);

    return notesCell;
}

private Cell CreatePriceCell(decimal price)
{
    // Create a price cell
    var priceCell = new Cell()
        .SetPadding(10);

    // Create an inner table for the price
    var tablePrice = new Table(1)
        .SetBackgroundColor(RegularBackgroundColor)
        .SetMargin(10)
        // if I set the width in percent, 
        //then the table is stretched to the width of the parent cell
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))
        // But if I set the height in percent,
        // the table is not stretched to the height of the parent cell!!!!
        .SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

    // Add a header of the inner table
    tablePrice.AddHeaderCell(new TextCell("Цена",
        BoldFont, TitleForegroundColor, false, TextAlignment.RIGHT));

    // Fill the inner table
    tablePrice.AddCell(new TextCell(price.ToString(), 
        LightFont, RegularForegroundColor, true, TextAlignment.RIGHT));

    // Add the inner table to the parent cell
    priceCell.Add(tablePrice);

    return priceCell;
}
```

As I indicated in the comments, if you set `SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue (100))` on the inner table, everything is fine - it stretches across the width of the parent cell. But if I set `SetHeight(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100))`, the inner table **does not** stretches across the height of the parent cell.
Here is the result:
[image]
In my previous question, I was advised to use `FormXObject`, but I don't know how can I apply it to my problem, because using `FormXObject` implies setting absolute sizes that I do not know initially:
`var tableTemplate = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(??, ??));`

Comment: You can also ser merge property for Price cell

Comment: @Nilay, I don't see this property? Where I can find it? why should I use it?

Comment: I mean use ColSpan/RowSpan for this. More Ref: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/colspan-and-rowspan

Comment: @Nilay, how does this help solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem myself. 
Now every inner table has no color, and I'm not trying to stretch it. This is most likely the most important. I paid much attention to cells and decided that I need to work with them. Why? Because each cell has a height equal to the maximum height of some cell in the row. And this is what I need

So, I want each cell to have a color, have margins, have rounded corners, and contain the content in the form of an internal table. In addition, each cell will have the same height automatically - what I was trying to achieve.

First, we need to create a custom Renderer for cells, that allows you to draw cells with margins(no by default) and with rounded corners. This is my Renderer for cells:

```
public class RoundCornerСellRenderer : CellRenderer
{
    public RoundCornerСellRenderer(Cell modelElement) : base(modelElement)
    {
    }

    public override IRenderer GetNextRenderer() =>
        new RoundCornerСellRenderer((Cell)GetModelElement());

    protected override Rectangle ApplyMargins(Rectangle rect, UnitValue[] margins, bool reverse)
    {
        var values = margins.Select(x => x.GetValue()).ToList();
        return rect.ApplyMargins(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], reverse);
    }

    public override void DrawBackground(DrawContext drawContext)
    {
        // Apply the margins
        var area = ApplyMargins(GetOccupiedAreaBBox(), GetMargins(), false);

        // Get background color
        var background = GetProperty<Background>(Property.BACKGROUND);
        var color = background.GetColor();

        // Draw the rectangle with rounded corners
        var canvas = drawContext.GetCanvas();
        canvas.SaveState();
        canvas.RoundRectangle(area.GetX(), area.GetY(), area.GetWidth(), area.GetHeight(), 5);
        canvas.SetFillColor(color);
        canvas.Fill();
        canvas.RestoreState();  
    } 
}
```

That's all! Now all you have to do is create cells, add them margins and this custom renderer:

```
private Cell CreateNotesCell(IList<ProductAttribute> notes)
{
    // Create a notes cell
    var notesCell = new Cell()
        .SetBackgroundColor(RegularBackgroundColor)
        .SetPadding(10)
        .SetMargins(20, 10, 20, 20);

    // Set the our custom renderer for the cell
    notesCell.SetNextRenderer(new RoundCornerСellRenderer(notesCell));

    // Create an inner table for the notes
    var tableNotes = new Table(1)
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

    // Add a header of the inner table
    tableNotes.AddHeaderCell(new TextCell("Примечание",
        BoldFont, TitleForegroundColor, false));

    // Fill the inner table
    foreach(var note in notes)
        tableNotes.AddCell(new TextCell($"{note.Name}: {string.Join(", ", note.Options)}", 
            LightFont, RegularForegroundColor));

    // Add the inner table to the parent cell
    notesCell.Add(tableNotes);

    return notesCell;
}

private Cell CreatePriceCell(decimal price)
{
    // Create a price cell
    var priceCell = new Cell()
        .SetBackgroundColor(RegularBackgroundColor)
        .SetPadding(10)
        .SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 10);

    // Set the our custom renderer for the cell
    priceCell.SetNextRenderer(new RoundCornerСellRenderer(priceCell));

    // Create an inner table for the price
    var tablePrice = new Table(1)
        .SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

    // Add a header of the inner table
    tablePrice.AddHeaderCell(new TextCell("Цена",
        BoldFont, TitleForegroundColor, false, TextAlignment.RIGHT));

    // Fill the inner table
    tablePrice.AddCell(new TextCell(price.ToString(), 
        LightFont, RegularForegroundColor, true, TextAlignment.RIGHT));

    // Add the inner table to the parent cell
    priceCell.Add(tablePrice);

    return priceCell;
}
```

And voila, we get cells with margins, rounded corners, and most importantly - they are stretched in height:

[image]